# SQL SERVER MERGE error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this source table for my merge and the target table has the same fields.

```
ID       Name           Birth            Work
123      john doe       01/20/2000       plumber
123      john doe       01/20/2000       carpenter
234      john ere       12/12/1990       driver
345      john wel       02/21/1998       janitor
```

but when I try to use Merge statement to transfer my data from source, it would prompt an error like "Duplicate primary key" and sometimes "Cannot update data since it has been updated once." How can I avoid these errors?

What I want to be done is, in my source table, it acts as an admission of workers(history) and my target data is the Master list. Can anyone help me how to avoid this errors?

This is my query:

```
MERGE EMPMASTER  as T
USING (Select ID,Name,Birth,Work from ADMISSION) as S
ON (CAST(T.IDNum as int)=Cast(S.ID as int))
WHEN NOT MATCHED by TARGET
THEN
INSERT (IDNum,EMPName,EMPBirth,EMPWork)

Values (ID,Name,Birth,Work)

WHEN MATCHED  THEN

UPDATE Set IDNum=ID,
           EMPName=Name,
           EMPBirth=Birth,
           EMPWork=Work);
```

So that in my Master list table it would look like:

```
ID       Name           Birth            Work
    123      john doe       01/20/2000       carpenter
    234      john ere       12/12/1990       driver
    345      john wel       02/21/1998       janitor
```

Comment: `Id` is the IDENTITY column??

Comment: yes ID is the Identity column

Comment: You can't insert the value of `IDENTITY` column.If it's only a primary key, then also it won't allow you to add duplicate values. You have to add the `ID` you are inserting as the `FK` in the new table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 
**duplicates**
on your source (based on the `ID`, which is your `MERGE ON` column).

You could either use grouping in your source so that it only takes **one value** per each `ID`, or you could cleanup the source beforehand to have only one record per `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining the Source and the Target tables on

```
(CAST(T.IDNum as int)=Cast(S.ID as int))
```

In your Source data sample, there are more than 1 row with same `ID (123)`.

Since your source and the target tables have same fields, you can join with 'Work' field as well, in order to **filter unique records in join combination**. Below is the query

```
MERGE EMPMASTER  as T
USING (Select ID,Name,Birth,Work from ADMISSION) as S
ON (CAST(T.IDNum as int)=Cast(S.ID as int))
and (CAST(T.EMPWork as varchar)=Cast(S.Work as varchar))
WHEN NOT MATCHED by TARGET
THEN
INSERT (IDNum,EMPName,EMPBirth,EMPWork)

Values (ID,Name,Birth,Work)

WHEN MATCHED  THEN

UPDATE Set IDNum=ID,
           EMPName=Name,
           EMPBirth=Birth,
           EMPWork=Work);
```